# Как сделать Button круглым?

Tags: c#

Как сделать Button круглым?

Comment: Вы используете WinForms или WPF?

Answer (score 5):

В WinForms можно сделать так.

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath myPath =
    new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
myPath.AddEllipse(0, 0, button1.Width, button1.Height);

Region myRegion = new Region(myPath);
button1.Region = myRegion;
```

Answer (score 2):

Если речь про WPF, то для изменения кнопки можно использовать новый стиль. В качестве исходных подойдут стили из, например, [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/blend_overview.aspx). Ход действий такой:

- берется готовый стиль для кнопки,
- в стиле заменяется ControlTemplate,
- стиль помещается в словарь ресурсов,
- словарь подключается к нужному модулю,
- стиль применяется к нужной кнопке (или всем кнопкам).

Ну, и собственно первоисточник.

- [Пошаговое руководство. Создание кнопки с помощью XAML.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb613545.aspx)
- [Пошаговое руководство. Создание кнопки с помощью Microsoft Expression Blend.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb613598.aspx)

P.S. В предельно упрощенном виде (сама идея) замена ControlTemplate выглядит так:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <Canvas>
                <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Control.Background}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Viewbox>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Button.Content}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```